# Will calling `SyncFolderItems` return items as they get received?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

Does calling `SyncFolderItems` in a loop (until `MoreChangesAvailable` is false) return items that have been received after my first call to `SyncFolderItems`?

For example, say I have 1,000 items in my mailbox and I make a call to `SyncFolderItems` with no sync state. After my first call to `SyncFolderItems` I receive an item will it include a new email I receive after I first call `SyncFolderItems`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each call to `SyncFolderItems` will [respond](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa566342%28v=EXCHG.140%29.aspx) with [`SyncState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa565970%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx) which is a hash of the timestamp and item index (*if > 512 items*) since the last synchronization call. When you call the `SyncFolderItems` again, you need to include the last `SyncState` to ensure you only get new items since your last synchronization point.

If you have [more than 512 items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa563967%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx) in the folder - you need to call `SyncFolderItems` again with the new `SyncState`.

Here is a [sample post](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchangesvrdevelopment/thread/ab5b2c0f-20b2-4751-a930-824f8b56d3b9/) using EWS Managed API.